# How to use featuretools at the test time?

Tags: python, pandas, featuretools

I would demonstrate the issue with an example:

Let us say we want to use the primitive 'PERCENTILE'

Imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import featuretools as ft
```

For training (create a simple data with one column and let featuretools compute a percentile feature on top of it):

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame({'index':[1,2,3,4,5], 'val':[1,2,3,4,5]})
es_train = ft.EntitySet("es_train")
es_train.add_dataframe(df_train,'df')
fm, fl = ft.dfs(entityset = es_train, trans_primitives=['percentile'], agg_primitives=[], target_dataframe_name='df')
```

output:

```
print(fm)
       val  PERCENTILE(val)
index                      
1        1              0.2
2        2              0.4
3        3              0.6
4        4              0.8
5        5              1.0
```

So far everything is expected

Now, when I get an example with the value, say, 3, at the test time. I would want it translated to 0.6 as per the training data. But, that is not what happens

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'index':[1], 'val':[3]})
es_test = ft.EntitySet("es_test")
es_test.add_dataframe(df_test,'df')
ft.calculate_feature_matrix(features = fl, entityset=es_test)
```

output:

```
       val  PERCENTILE(val)
index                      
1        3              1.0
```

So, metadata in feature definitions in `fl` that is the output of `ft.dfs` does not store train time stats needed to compute the features at the test time. This would throw any machine-learning model into a tailspin

What is the canonical way to apply featuretools at the test time?